# Difficulties running JavaScript (from .js file) in an Angular application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, add-in

I am trying to incorporate a Javascript function (contained in app.js), which I am trying to run from the index.html of my Angular 2 application.

Initially I used a CLI program called Office Add-in generator to make a non-angular application, in which this JavaScript works.

However when using the Add-in generator in an Angular application the app.js file is not automatically generated. Manually copy pasting the app.js file and `<script>` link does not work either. I realise I have only provided a couple of files worth of code, let me know if I should edit more in, or provide a github link?

The error in chrome is net::ERR_ABORTED not defined with a 404 message. (relating to the app.js file)

~~~~HTML~~~~~

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Microsoft Graph Connect sample</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>
    window.history.replaceState = function(){};
    window.history.pushState = function(){};
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <button onclick="setItemBody()">Paste to email</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/core-js/client/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/office-ui-fabric-js/dist/js/fabric.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

~~~~~~~app.js~~~~~~~~

```
var item;

Office.initialize = function () {
    item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready function.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // After the DOM is loaded, app-specific code can run.
        // Set data in the body of the composed item.
       // setItemBody();
    });
}

// Get the body type of the composed item, and set data in 
// in the appropriate data type in the item body.
function setItemBody() {
    item.body.getTypeAsync(
        function (result) {
            if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                write(result.error.message);
            }
            else {
                // Successfully got the type of item body.
                // Set data of the appropriate type in body.
                if (result.value == Office.MailboxEnums.BodyType.Html) {
                    // Body is of HTML type.
                    // Specify HTML in the coercionType parameter
                    // of setSelectedDataAsync.
                    item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
                        '<b>These are the times I am available:</b><br>Monday -- 8:30 to 9:00<br>Tuesday -- 1:00 to 5:00<br>Thursday -- 4:00 to 5:00<br>',
                        { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html, 
                        asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 } },
                        function (asyncResult) {
                            if (asyncResult.status == 
                                Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                                write(asyncResult.error.message);
                            }
                            else {
                                // Successfully set data in item body.
                                // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                                // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                            }
                        });
                }
                else {
                    // Body is of text type. 
                    item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
                        ' Kindly note we now open 7 days a week.',
                        { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text, 
                            asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 } },
                        function (asyncResult) {
                            if (asyncResult.status == 
                                Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                                write(asyncResult.error.message);
                            }
                            else {
                                // Successfully set data in item body.
                                // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                                // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                            }
                         });
                }
            }
        });

}

// Writes to a div with id='message' on the page.
function write(message){
    document.getElementById('message').innerText += message; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should not just put your js files in index.html better add in .angular-cli.json file.. and about js not working in ng2+ project.. check out https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives I think you must make wrapper. check this as well https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc